# SQL Server restriction by IP

Tags: sql-server, database, ip-restrictions

My client's application access an Azure SQL Server database. This database has IP restrictions (only registered IPs can access the database). My IP is dynamic and I cannot change it at the moment.

In case I get a VPN with a dedicated IP address, would I be able to access the database? Or is it possible that they also have some restrictions that identify if I am using a VPN (I do not know if that is possible)?

Thank you all.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with VPN, still they will have to trust your VPN vendor. Do you have any VPN vendor in mind?

Comment: Oh ok, so in that case I would have to tell them I am using a VPN? I am still checking, but I found this one called NordVPNTeams. I would like to make it seems transparent to them.

Answer (score 0):

Going via a VPN will likely increase your latency, but it will provide a fixed IP address that the Azure firewall will see. If this IP address is allowed access then you will be OK.

The other option would be to create a VM in Azure and run your queries from there - this will be easier for them to grant access to as it is likely that access from Azure will already be enabled.